# How to only make one div has toggled at one time when using toggle class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#items").children().click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='items'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Now, I can toggleClass to make div become red color when click.
But I can still click another div to make it red then I will have two div in red color.

How to only make one div become red at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#items").children().click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked') // toggle class of current element
               .siblings('div') // get siblings of current elem
               .removeClass('clicked'); // remove class clicked from siblings

    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#items").children().click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings('div').removeClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='items'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeClass` and `not` to exclude the current selection:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#items").children().click(function(){
    $('#items > div').not($(this).toggleClass('clicked')).removeClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='items'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

### A shorter version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#items").children().click(function(){
    $('.clicked').not($(this).toggleClass('clicked')).removeClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class of `clicked` from all the other sibling `div`s.

Use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select the sibling elements.

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#items").children().click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings('div').removeClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='items'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#items").children().click(function() {
    $(this) //clicked element
        .add('.clicked', this.parentNode)//add already '.clicked' child element in jq set
        .toggleClass('clicked');//toggle class for all elements in set
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='items'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not obvious how it works (without explanation) but cute approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#items").children().click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

Comment: This version does not toggle the current selection if it is re-clicked. presumably that is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

HI now try to this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#items > div").click(function(){
       $("#items").children().removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
      });
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#items > div").click(function(){
   $("#items").children().removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='items'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This version does not toggle the current selection if it is re-clicked. presumably that is the requirement.